# Upload video file to server

Tags: ios, swift, upload

I have uploaded video file to server but the file size is zero.

```
let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: (Config.sampleuploadurl as String)+"/uploadServlet?chehara_email=\(candit_email)")
// let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: (Config.apiUrl as String)+"/UploadServlet?chehara_email=\(candit_email)")
print(url)
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let boundaryConstant = "Boundary-7MA4YWxkTLLu0UIW"; // This should be auto-generated.
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant

let fileName:String = videoName

let mimeType = "text/MOV"
let fieldName = "uploadFile"

request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

var error: NSError?
var dataString = "--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n"

dataString += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n"
print("dataString")

dataString += "Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n"
print(dataString)

dataString += String(contentsOfFile: videoName, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)!   // This is Error Line

dataString += "\r\n"
dataString += "--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n"

let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print("Request")
print(requestBodyData)

request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData
print(request.HTTPBody)

})
```

I refer this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/janporu-san/e832cdee51974fc55660).

Comment: `file name` you get data or not

Comment: I'm surprised to see a movie encoded in UTF8, shouldn't you use a NSData ?

Comment: ya i get MOV file and upload the mov file but contant  of size  Zero

Comment: How to use NSData or else?

Answer (score 0):

Eric,
You should not use NSMutableURLRequest, You should use NSURLSession. Here is some I code I posted else

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604866/swift-send-file-to-server/35609325#35609325
```

This post I replied too shows its implementation. NSMutableURLRequest is being depreciated.

And here is a 1 of several excellent tutorials on the subject; and no I am not Bart Jakobs in disguise :)

```
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394
```